# Cannot find and delete default 'Home' page in pages list

Tags: php, wordpress

I am starting a wordpress  website and created my first page called 'home'  but when I go to view my site I have 2 home pages and I can only edit and delete the one that I made ,how do I delete the default home page? as many people suggest searched default home menu in header.php there is no menu link like that how can i delete the default menu in wordpress.where can i find menu list?

thanks in advance

Comment: set page from setting option

Comment: set menu as primary menu from admin and drag n drop your home page in that

Comment: Go to Appearance -> Menus and select primary menu and Remove home Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Have You seen your post section?Goto Appreance >Menu
To Remove the default Home menu by clicking on it and click on remove link.
Thanks